# How does DNS know which machine on my router to talk to?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, port-forwarding, nat

I have a server that is accessible via ssh at foo.university.edu, and my workstation is on the same router (which has a decent hardware firewall). When I check my workstation's public IP, I find it is x.x.123.4, and when I check what the IP address for foo.university.edu is, it is exactly the same. This is unsurprising to me, as I understand this to merely be the public IP of my router. I understand how Network Address Translation (NAT) can play games to allow each machine to access external information, or at least I think I do. Importantly, this does not allow an external machine to talk directly to any of my networked machines unless it is configured to use port forwarding.

Let's say that on my router, the server foo has local IP 192.168.1.100 and my workstation is at .101. When I ssh into foo, how does everything know that I need to be connecting to 100? Is it merely that there there is no other machine listening on port 22?

What would happen if I connected another server to this network? Let's say I connected a new server on my router at 192.168.1.102, and I set it to accept ssh from port 1000 (or something). If I then used putty to ssh in to foo.university.edu at port 1000, would I be able to ssh into .102 because it would be the only thing listening there?

Answer (score 0):

> How does DNS know which machine on my router to talk to?

It doesn't. DNS directly maps a given human-readable URL to a computer-friendly IP address (i.e
 the one for your router). So in DNS,  `foo.university.edu` maps to `x.x.123.4`.

> Let's say that on my router, the server foo has local IP 192.168.1.100 and my workstation is at .101. When I `ssh` into foo, how does everything know that I need to be connecting to 100?

You router handles this. Assuming that you have opted to port forward communication on port 22 (`ssh`) to 192.168.1.100, your router keeps track of this information. Then when Computer A (e.g. your Workstation) contacts your router on port 22 (`ssh`), your router sees that port 22 is being used and it needs to forward that communication to 192.168.1.100.

> Let's say I connected a new server on my router at 192.168.1.102, and I set it to accept ssh from port 1000 (or something). If I then used putty to ssh in to foo.university.edu at port 1000, would I be able to ssh into .102 because it would be the only thing listening there?

No, not automatically. At least not typically. You would have to explicitly port forward port 1000 to 192.168.1.102. The exception to this rule would be if your router had a "DMZ" setting, which is an IP address that it would send all unknown requests for communication to.